# How to specify commit and branch in csproj for nuget package creation

Tags: nuget-package, csproj, nuspec

So currently you could configure the branch and commit a .nuspec (see [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec)):

```xml
<repository type="git" 
            url="https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client.git" 
            branch="dev" 
            commit="e1c65e4524cd70ee6e22abe33e6cb6ec73938cb3" />
```

But how could we configure that from the SDK-style .csproj files? Currently I have the type and url:

```xml
<RepositoryType>git</RepositoryType>
<RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/NLog/NLog.git</RepositoryUrl>
```

and I can't find the correct elements or attributes for "branch" and "commit". It's also not on this page: [MSDN - Additions to the csproj format for .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj).

So how could I configure the branch and commit when creating nuget packages from a sdk-style csproj?

Answer (score 8):

The properties you're looking for are as follows:

```xml
<RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/your/repository.git</RepositoryUrl>
<RepositoryBranch>release2.2</RepositoryBranch> <!-- optional branch reference -->
<RepositoryCommit>24ca19c71e8a84eeb8b9d3f95faa4b244db4341b</RepositoryCommit> <!-- optional commit reference -->
```

Note that these are simply added to the package metadata and you will still only build whatever you have locally.